# How to avoid time complexity O(n^2)?

Tags: java, loops, collections, time-complexity

I have this following piece of code:

```
for(ArticleBasketInBean basketBean : bean.getBasket()) {
    for(ArticleDTO article : dto.getArticleList()) {
        if(basketBean.getArticleReference().equals(article.getArticleReference())) {
            article.setAddedToBasket(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Clearly the time complexity of the above operation is O(n^2). For this case `articleReference` is unique. So the list returned by `bean.getBasket()` has no duplicate `articleReference`, also this is true for the list returned by `dto.getArticleList()`.

I want to avoid this nested iteration and want to write faster code. How can I do that?

Comment: You'd need some kind of index structure, for example a HashMap. But is the nested loop really a problem? How many articles are we talking about?

Comment: Simple trick to reduce iterations: `break` out of the inner loop after the first match. Still O(n^2), though.

Comment: You can improve this a little bit, but in the worst case, it'll always be O(n^2).

Comment: @Thilo you mean I shall iterate the `dto.getArticleList()` first and put the `articleReference` and `article` in the map, then iterate over `bean.getBasket()` and for each `articleRefernce` of the basket, I do a get from the map and set the value to that returned `article`?

Comment: Do you have many lookups like that in your code?

Comment: @fge He can also main both an HashSet and a List. The first is to get a specific instance by using the hashcode (i.e. the key), the second for iteration purposes.

Comment: @fge I am not sure I clearly understand you. How the implementation of equals/hashcode and use of `HashSet` will help me avoid the O(n^2)! the classes are different.

Comment: @MarounMaroun the issue is chosing the right data structure. Replace the `articleList` by a `HashMap` and voilà! O(n)

Comment: @JeanValjean sorry, that was a mistake from my part

Comment: @TapasBose HashSet is a Set that includes a "set" of objects. It is a data structure used to get the objects by using the hashcode associated to the object: a very fast approach!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have too many articles/baskets and as you say the references are unique you can do something like this; let's call `R` the type of the reference, `A` the type of articles, `B` the type of baskets:

```
// since all references are unique we can use that, but see below
Map<R, A> mappedArticles = new IdentityHashMap<>();

// inject articles based on references in the map, then

A article;

for (B basket: bean.getBasket())
    article = mappedArticles.get(basket.getArticleReferences());
    if (article != null)
        article.setAddedToBasket(true);

// Full list of articles is in the map's .values()
```

Notes:

- note the use of an **identity** hashset; you may want to implement equals/hashcode for the references instead (or maybe the type you use has them already implemented for you);
- your map may be filled as articles "flow by", in this case you can create it only once (make it thread safe if so!).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have `hashcode` and `equals` for article. Two questions I have, I know that `IdentityHashMap` use `==` operator for comparing objects, which is `equals` in case of `HashMap`. What is the extra performance bonus I can achieve by using `IdentityHashMap` instead of `HashMap`? I haven't use `IdentityHashMap` before, so do I need to override the `equals` method as: `that.getArticleReference() == this.getArticleReference();}` or `this.getArticleReference().equals(that.getArticleReference()`

Comment: If you have hashCode and equals already there is no need for an `IdentityHashMap`; they are really there for reference equality only ;)

Answer (score 5):

Use `java.util.HashSet` to cache one of the sets of references, assuming the sets are not TOO large, of course.  With a good hash function, this should bring you back to O(n).

Answer (score 1):

A simple `break` will save you.

```
    for(ArticleBasketInBean basketBean : bean.getBasket()) {
    for(ArticleDTO article : dto.getArticleList()) {
        if(basketBean.getArticleReference().
                                  equals(article.getArticleReference())) {
            article.setAddedToBasket(true);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does not change the order, only makes it slightly faster.

Answer (score 0):

This is where **hashMap** Data Structure comes to rescue. It's not any rocket science, simply :

> an object with key, value pair

The complexity will reduce from O(n2) to O(n), which is better.